# proof of Strong Markov property check

Tags: mathematical-statistics, markov-process

#### Statement

We say $\Phi$ has the *strong Markov Property* if for any initial distribution $\mu$, any real-valued bounded measurable function $h$ on $\Omega$, and any stopping time $\zeta$,
$$
\mathsf{E}_{\mu}[\theta^\zeta H \mid \mathcal{F}_\zeta^\Phi] = \mathsf{E}_{\Phi_\zeta}[H] \hspace{10mm} \mathsf{P}_\mu \text{-a.s.}
$$
on the set $\{\zeta < \infty\}$.

#### Proof

\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}_{\mu}[\theta^\zeta H \mid \mathcal{F}_\zeta^\Phi] 
&= \mathsf{E}_{\mu}[\theta^\zeta H \sum_{k \ge 1} \mathbb{I}(\zeta = k) \mid \mathcal{F}_\zeta^\Phi] \tag{mult by $1$}\\
&= \sum_{k \ge 1} \mathsf{E}_{\mu}[\theta^\zeta H  \mathbb{I}(\zeta = k) \mid \mathcal{F}_\zeta^\Phi] \tag{linearity} \\
&= \sum_{k \ge 1} \mathsf{E}_{\mu}[\theta^k H  \mathbb{I}(\zeta = k) \mid \mathcal{F}_\zeta^\Phi] \tag{$\theta^\zeta = \theta^k$ on $\{\zeta = k\}$ by defn.} \\ 
&= \sum_{k \ge 1} \mathbb{I}(\zeta = k) \mathsf{E}_{\mu}[\theta^k H   \mid \mathcal{F}_\zeta^\Phi] \tag{indicator is $\mathcal{F}_\zeta^\Phi$-measurable} \\
&= \sum_{k \ge 1} \mathbb{I}(\zeta = k) \mathsf{E}_{\mu}[\theta^k H   \mid \mathcal{F}_k^\Phi] \tag{?} \\
&= \sum_{k \ge 1} \mathbb{I}(\zeta = k) \mathsf{E}_{\Phi_k}[ H] \tag{(the other) Markov property} \\
&= \sum_{k \ge 1} \mathbb{I}(\zeta = k) \mathsf{E}_{\Phi_\zeta}[ H]  \tag{?} \\
&=   \mathsf{E}_{\Phi_\zeta}[ \sum_{k \ge 1} \mathbb{I}(\zeta = k) H]  \\
&= \mathsf{E}_{\Phi_\zeta}[H]
\end{align}

#### Definitions

- $\Phi = \{\Phi_0, \Phi_1, \ldots\}$ is the chain defined on $\Omega = \mathsf{X}^{\infty}$
- $\mu$ is the chain's initial distribution on $(\mathsf{X}, \mathcal{X})$
- $\mathsf{E}_\mu$ and $\mathsf{P}_\mu$ are the expectation and probability measure defined on the entire product measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$
- $\zeta$ is the stopping time
- $\mathcal{F}_{\zeta}^\Phi$ is the sigma-field that describes all the events that happen up to time $\zeta$
- $\theta^{\zeta} : \{x_0, x_1, \ldots\} \mapsto \{x_{\zeta}, x_{\zeta+1}, \ldots\}$ is the (random) shift operator
- $H = h(\Phi_0, \Phi_1, \ldots)$ is a random variable made from the bounded measurable function $h$
- $\theta^\zeta H = H \circ \theta^\zeta(\omega)$ is the function $h$ applied to randomly-delayed chain

#### Questions And Comments

I can do
$$
\mathbb{I}(\zeta = k) \mathsf{E}_{\mu}[\theta^k H   \mid \mathcal{F}_\zeta^\Phi] 
= \mathbb{I}(\zeta = k) \mathsf{E}_{\mu}[\theta^k H   \mid \mathcal{F}_k^\Phi] 
$$
because

$$
\int_A \mathbb{I}(\zeta = k) \mathsf{E}_{\mu}[\theta^k H   \mid \mathcal{F}_\zeta^\Phi] \mathsf{P}_\mu(d\omega)
= \int_A \mathbb{I}(\zeta = k) \mathsf{E}_{\mu}[\theta^k H   \mid \mathcal{F}_k^\Phi] \mathsf{P}_\mu(d\omega) \tag{*}
$$
for any $A \in \mathcal{F}_\zeta^\Phi$, right? By definition of $\mathcal{F}_\zeta^\Phi$
$$
A \cap \{\zeta = k\} \in \mathcal{F}_k
$$
so $\mathbb{I}(\omega \in A)\mathbb{I}(\zeta = k)$ is $\mathcal{F}_k$-measurable. This gives us that both sides of $(*)$ equal $\mathsf{E}_{\mu}[\mathbb{I}(\omega \in A)\theta^k H ]$.

Comment: You write $$ \mathsf{E}_{\mu}[\theta^\zeta H \sum_{k \ge 1} \mathbb{I}(\zeta = k) \mid \mathcal{F}_\zeta^\Phi] $$ but what is $\zeta$ to which $k$ can be compared in the indicator function?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus it's the stopping time. I'm doing the thing where I partition up $\Omega$ and multiply by $\mathbb{I}(A) + \mathbb{I}(A^c)$

Comment: But isn't the stopping time multivalued? For instance, if you have a Brownian motion and consider the stopping time the time when the particle hits some boundary or passes some level, what is then $\mathbb{I}(\zeta = k)$? Which value do you put in?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus this is a discrete-time Markov chain, and so this is a countable sum. Random variables that take into account stopping times are defined piecewise on individual sets. On the set $\{\zeta = k\} \subseteq \Omega$, $\zeta$ evaluates to $k$

Comment: So you are looking for the [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta#Properties) $\sum_{k} \delta_{k,\zeta} \mathsf{E}_{\mu}[\theta^\zeta H  \mid \mathcal{F}_\zeta^\Phi] = \mathsf{E}_{\mu}[\theta^k H  \mid \mathcal{F}_k^\Phi]$ with $\delta_{k,\zeta}$ the Kronecker delta.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus yes that was the part that gave me pause when I was writing this out

Comment: After reading this question I have been looking up some stuff about the strong property. It seems to me that, if the transition probabilities are uniform in time, then it is a relatively clear that a discrete time Markov process is also a strong Markov process. But for the continuous time case, there might be issues with points of discontinuity and what happens to the property when you get a limit to the discontinuity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two question marked steps are indeed correct. This proof also follows the proof given for Proposition 3.4.6 [here](http://probability.ca/MT/Chap3.pdf). Note that the assumption of $P(\tau = \infty) = 0$ comes into play when [we sum over $1,2,\ldots$.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/403399/what-does-the-pmf-of-a-discrete-random-variable-look-like-if-it-can-take-on-the)